# Find jvm from Java

Tags: java, jvm, cross-platform

How can I find a JVM ( java command, e.g. */usr/bin/java* for mac and *C:\Program Files\Java\bin\java.exe* for Windows) from a Java application?

Reason:
I am running an JNLP application that should download and launch other jar. I cannot just load the other jar because it has native libraries which could not be launched as JNLP.

Comment: You can use the java Desktop API, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html, to "open" the jar file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could figure this out by using the `java.home` system property, which returns the path to the currently running jvm.

```
System.getProperty("java.home");
```

To be truly platform independent, you'd need to combine this with some platform detection to decide whether to append "bin/java" or "bin\java.exe", but it should be reasonably straightforward to do using some of the other [system properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29).

Comment: but *java.home* is defined even to non-developer machines?

Comment: You're confusing JAVA_HOME (JDK environment variable) with "java.home" which is set if you have a JRE installed.

Comment: The java.home system property is one of several that is *always* (by the java standard) available. It's available regardless of VM version, vendor, or operating system, or whether it's JDK or JRE, etc. Check out the link in the post for more details.

Answer (score 0):

On unix like platforms you can try :
which java

which command is used to identify the location of executables